# Filemaker Pro Export Records script step failing

Tags: filemaker

(FMPA 12.0v5)

I have a script with 1 script step: "export records".

"run script with full access privileges" is checked for the script.

When I run the script under a full access privilege set, it works (it displays an export dialog, then exports the file).

When I run the script under a privilege set where "allow exporting" is unchecked, it fails (it does not display an export dialog, and does not export any file).

This doesn't sound correct. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What you described should work. I think we missing some information.  Can you reproduce the problem in a very simple file?

Comment: I also posed the question in this other location 
[link](http://fmforums.com/forum/topic/90923-export-records-script-step-not-working/), and seem to be making a little progress, but it's not solved yet. 
I use 2 filemaker files, one for data, the other for UI. the script is in the UI database. Your question prompted me to make a test, by putting the script in the data database. Sure enough, it worked! I don't understand why, and I would prefer to have the script in the UI database.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is correct, given you have logged in with an account that is member of a privilege set that does not allow exporting (as unchecked in the allow exporting).

You have two options;

1. Allowing to export in that privilege set
2. Mark the checkbox at the bottom of your script editor that says "execute with full privileges".